# How to trigger Vite HMR updates without having to save the file first?

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I noticed that on some playground sites the preview updates instantly, and I found it very useful while working on CSS files. Stackblitz and Vue SFC Playground have that default behavior.
Also, StackBlitz let us switch the two modes, but I cannot find where this setting is saved.

How to replicate this on my local dev environment?

Comment: If changes do not persist on the disk, what reactions do you expect to be done? I think they are leveraging a debounce function to save changes in the background. Your IDE must provide you with this option by storing modifications periodically.

Comment: Of course there is a communication in the background, but it's not a real auto-save on the actual file.  While working, I see on console HMR updates, but the file shows the "unsaved" little circle next to the filename (VS Code on web).  If I quit, the system warns for unsaved changes